# How to clarify a question when the original question was wrong

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I posted a question to Stack Overflow, and then from responses in the comments figured out a fix, but I don't understand why the fix works the way it does.

I think this second question would be much more helpful. Should I answer the original post with the fix, then ask a follow-up in the answer, or edit the original question, or post and entirely new question?

Comment: To me, answering the original question implies you know why that answer works the way it does. You should never ask a question in an answer, and you shouldn't edit a question to be a new question because it could invalidate answers. Seems like that leaves one method, posting a new question (as long as it would still be on-topic)

Comment: You can ask for the explanation in the comments by @ them or if it's long then ask  them to post it as an answer with the explanation and accept the answer

Comment: There's also option D. The comments and fix have left you with a new question - why does it work? Try to read anything and everything you can find about that to understand it, maybe even experimenting a little with the code. Don't immediately ask the follow-up question because the answer is likely already out there. I'm not saying don't ask, but first go through the whole process of searching for an answer. It's a good habit.

Comment: You should **never** ask a follow-up question in the answer. Answers are not for questions. If you have a new question, you should post a new question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since the initial insight came in the form of a comment, rather than an answer, editing your original question to clarify—and even modify—the scope is appropriate.

You never want to make edits that change the substance of a question after it has received answers, since moving the goalposts after the fact is unfair. However, comments don’t count.

Once you’ve modified the question, you may want to ping the commenter who provided the intial insight and give them the opportunity to answer. Or, you might want to answer the question yourself, taking care to give credit to the user who got you on the right track.

In certain cases, you may still feel that the edits that would be required to the question are too extreme, even if you haven’t received any answers. In these cases, it may make more sense to ask a follow-up question. Keep the original as a “how” question, and then ask a second “why does this work?” question. You can always link to the original question from the follow-up question to provide context. Whether splitting it up into multiple questions is appropriate is, ultimately, a judgement call. And it is one best left to someone who is familiar with the topic. Consider that our goal is bite-sized problems and solutions (Q&A). We don’t want questions that are too broad or require extremely long answers, so if it keeps things clearer to split them up, then go ahead and do so. On the other hand, the “why” is often part and parcel of any good explanation of the “how”, so splitting them up may just make the useful information harder to find.

Comment: How do I 'ping' somebody?

Comment: @ouflak Like this. :-) For more details, please see [the canonical FAQ on comment replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: "You never want to make edits that change the substance of a question after it has received answers" this is not only counter productive, it's absurd. If a question is unclear and someone answers with a Hail Mary that still doesn't solve the problem, the asker would be stuck with a question that doesn't reflect the problem they are facing and an answer that doesn't solve it either. Post should always be the best version of themselves. It's not the fault of the asker that someone instead of asking for clarification jumped the gun guessing.